# Existence Lebesgue integral and Lebesgue integrability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have a question related to the existence of Lebesgue Integral. Here  in the paragraph "signed function", we read that the Lebesgue integral exists provided that 
$$(1) \min(\int_{E}f^+d\mu, \int_Rf^{-}d\mu)<\infty$$
 Then we read that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable provided that $$(2) \int_R|f|d\mu<\infty$$

Which relation is between the two conditions?

> My understanding is that: (2)--> (1)<-->Existence Lebesgue Integral,
>   i.e. the Lebesgue integral exists even if a function is not
>   Lebesgue integrable. Moreover (2) implies that the Lebesgue integral is finite. Is it correct?

Any hint would be really appreciated; I think my intuition is wrong because I found in many proof that a function $f$ can be Lebesgue integrable with a Lebesgue integral not necessarily finite. What is wrong in my argument?

Comment: Not all authors agree on the definitions or terminology.  What to remember is that, unlike the situation for improper Riemann integrals, one always uses $$ \int_{E}f \,d\mu= \int_{E}f^+d\mu - \int_Ef^{-}d\mu  $$ so that either (i) do this only when both are finite or (ii) allow this as long as one at least is finite, but always (iii) never ever permit both to be infinite since $\infty-\infty$ makes no sense.  So you get texts that say "$f$ is integrable" or "the integral $\int f$ exists"  and might mean different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(2) implies (1). When (1) holds and (2) does not, the Lebesgue integral exists but it is equal to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. We distinguish this from the case when (2) holds through the two definitions.